# Is  ∩ () = ∅ true for A = { 1 } ? Or is  ∩ () = { 1 } ? (Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is  ∩ () = ∅ true for A = { 1 } ? Or is  ∩ () = { 1 } ?

A = {1}

P(A) = {0, {1}}

Is  ∩ () = ∅ or is  ∩ () = {1}?

My train of thought is that  ∩ () = ∅ should be true as A contains the integer 1, while P(A) contains the set {1} which is different from the integer?

I've looked at the existing answers on the internet but I keep getting mixed responses.

An additional question is, is  ∩ () always ∅ for all kinds of sets A?

Comment: It is empty indeed

Comment: Why do you use 0 for the empty set in the body of your question?

Answer (score 7):

You are exactly right: $1$ is equal to neither $\{1\}$ nor $\varnothing$, so $1 \notin \mathcal{P}(A)$. Since $1$ is the only element of $A$, $A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ have no elements in common, i.e. $A \cap \mathcal{P}(A) = \varnothing$.

In general, though, it is possible to have a set $X$ such that $X \cap \mathcal{P}(X) \neq \varnothing$! To produce an example, you want to find a set $X$ such that one of the elements of $X$ is also a subset of $X$. Can you make that happen?

Comment: Oh I just thought of it, thanks! so when A = {1, {1}}, P(A) = {empty set, {1}, {{1}}, {1, {1}}}! so the common element is {1}

Comment: @physeeks Correct. Actually a set is by definition *transitive* if $A\subseteq P(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

The $\mathcal{P} (A) = \{ \emptyset,\{1\} \}$ because it is the collection of all subsets of A. Including A itself. But A has no elements in common with $\mathcal{P} (A)$ as $ \{1\} \neq 1$
Thus $\mathcal{P} (A) \cap A = \emptyset $

Comment: You forgot to type \ in front of {